# how top put minHours and maxHours in datetimepicker Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

I have a problem, I need to have only hours between 8:00 - 17:00 and also 00:00 in my `datetimepicker`, I have already put `minuteStep`, but I can put `minHour` and `maxHour`

```
    <datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.dateDropDownInput"
        data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown2',minuteStep:30 }">
    </datetimepicker>
```

I don't use the controller for minuteStep:30, so if it is possible to put (maxhour and min hours) in data-datetimepicker-config, it would be cool. :D

Answer (score 0):

Use the [before-render](https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker#before-render) callback to disable the dates that should not be selected by the user.